# local admin account powershell script

Tags: windows-10, powershell, script

I have created a powershell script that will apply to the computer during login using a GPO to create a local admin account. We are implementing LAPS. My supervisor doesn't want to use the built-in administrator account. I am using the following script

```
    New-LocalUser -AccountNeverExpires:$true -Password ( ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 'Password123!') -Name 'nwcaluser' |
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group administrators
```

The GPO is being applied to the computers.  It doesn't appear the script is running.  The script will be disabled once it was created the new local admin account on all PCs.  We will be modifying our SCCM image for all future computers.  Can anyone assist?

Comment: "It doesn't appear the script is running." - Please provide specifics.  Are you saying when you run the command it does nothing, or are you saying something else, the statement is not clear.

Comment: I can run the script manually without issue.  I have a GP setup to run the script at startup.  It doesn't appear the script is running since i am not seeing the local admin acct that it's suppose to create.

Comment: You should consider using a GP preference item to do this.

Comment: can't due to this. https://msrc-blog.microsoft.com/2014/05/13/ms14-025-an-update-for-group-policy-preferences/

Comment: Whatever method you use to run the script, must elevated the permissions of the PowerShell command prompt, in order for the command to do anything.  Otherwise, it will silently fail, due to a lack of permissions.  I assume you are logging into an Administrator user account (Local & Domain) when this script is ran?